# I want to take a data value from plugin booking checkout from to woocommerce checkout form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: this booking plugin checkout form]

[image: This woocommerce checkout form]

I require the information I input into the booking plugin's checkout form to automatically fill in the Woocommerce checkout form.